How to calculate the volume energy loss function (VELF) using Quantum ESPRESSO?
How to calculate the volume energy loss function (VELF)?
Could you please share with a simple example (with related input files, output files and/or plot)?
Any relevant links would also be welcome.

Using QE, you can calculate $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ (I see that you already have these). Then the loss function is defined as $\epsilon_2 / (\epsilon_1^2 + \epsilon_2^2)$. You can plot them against either $E$ or $\omega$. See equation (12) and figure 3 of this paper as an example.

Thanks @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine. It makes sense.

I see that the loss functions are not defined in same ways for SELF and VELF. For example: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.memori.2023.100085, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.synthmet.2014.05.013, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.rinp.2013.08.004. I am seeing these three links, all are showing different equations. Do you have any link (preferably a book link) which shows their derivations? Because I see that all of the above three links have their citations to claim the validity of their used equations - so multiple other papers used the same form of equations for each paper. @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine
